# Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction [...] A connection could not be obtained for driver class "null" and URL "null"

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat7

I'm having an issue connecting to my DB in a Spring based web application hosted on Tomcat 7.  In my search for a solution I've found many people who have had similar issues but none of their solutions seem to work for me. I'm developing in Eclipse (RAD 8.5).

Here is the stack trace:

```
2015-05-18_13:36:49.625 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR c.m.g.s.TenancyDetailsServiceImpl - Error condition: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There were errors initializing your configuration: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: A connection could not be obtained for driver class "null" and URL "null".  You may have specified an invalid URL.
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newConnectException(DataSourceFactory.java:255)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.installDBDictionary(DataSourceFactory.java:241)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:733)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(ConfigurationImpl.java:310)
at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:1670)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:651)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:203)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:153)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:445)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:366)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.getTransaction(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:336)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.getTenancyDetailsWithTenantCode(Unknown Source)
at com.m.gsp.serviceimpl.TenancyDetailsServiceImpl.getTenancyDetailsWithTenantCode(TenancyDetailsServiceImpl.java:70)
at com.m.gsp.helper.TenancyDelegate.getTenancyDetailsWithTenantCode(TenancyDelegate.java:42)
at com.m.gsp.utils.WebUtils.fetchTenancyDetails(WebUtils.java:609)
at com.m.gsp.controllers.AuthenticationController.renderLoginPage(AuthenticationController.java:128)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at com.m.gsp.tenancy.TenantDispatcherServlet.service(TenantDispatcherServlet.java:101)
at com.m.gsp.tenancy.TenantDispatcherServletProxy.service(TenantDispatcherServletProxy.java:82)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.m.gsp.logging.MDCServletFilter.doFilter(MDCServletFilter.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at com.m.gsp.tenancy.security.TenantDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(TenantDelegatingFilterProxy.java:65)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
```

Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:sqlserver:AX-RISCVMSQL74\SQL74:1435;databaseName=GSPVN;'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:116)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.getConnection(DecoratingDataSource.java:93)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.installDBDictionary(DataSourceFactory.java:233)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:289)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 89 more

Context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/salesvietnamMssqlGspDS"
auth="Container"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="50"
maxIdle="10"
maxWait="15000"
username="x"
password="y"
url="jdbc:sqlserver:server/instance:port;databaseName=dbname;"
removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="30"
logAbandoned="true" />
```

Application's WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
<description>JDBCconnection</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/salesvietnamMssqlGspDS</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

I even put the same resource-ref in the server's web.xml as well.

sqljdbc4.jar is present in the server's `/lib` directory. 
I added it to the Classpath under user entries in the run configurations menu.
I even tried adding it in the build path and deployment assembly, I've verified it does show up in WEB-INF/lib.

None of the above have had any effect.

I read about needing to register the driver using `Class.forName("something.jdbc.driver.YourFubarDriver");` but then I also read that was no longer necessary with JDBC4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further inspection of the logs I realized that I had a malformed URL in my resource definition in context.xml, I changed it from:

`url="jdbc:sqlserver:server/instance:port;databaseName=dbname;"`
 to this:
`url="jdbc:sqlserver://server\instance:port;databaseName=dbname;"`